# why is my list-style-type:katakana not working in my class

Tags: html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/scn6l.png

I need to create a list with katakana, so I created a class .lisDestaq with list-style-type:katakana, but when I load the class in div it doesn't work.

```
.lisDestaq{
color:#2255AA;
list-style-type:katakana;
}
```

then on html

```
<div class="lisDestaq">
    <ul>
        <li> Death Note </li>
    </ul>
```

but the katakana doesn't show up
I can just put in css `ul{list-style-type:katakana;}` and it works, but I want to set it into the class, can somebody help me? why isn't working?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLs7S.png

Comment: You're not targeting the list.  Do this instead: `.lisDestaq ul`.  Of course, I could be wrong, but that seems on first glance to me to be a relevant thing.

Comment: ahhhh it works now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use this in your css **`.lisDestaq ul`** instead of **`.lisDestaq`** you need to set on child class also and you are just set to `div` class

**CSS**

```
.lisDestaq ul{
  color: #2255AA;
  list-style-type: katakana;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="lisDestaq">
  <ul>
    <li> Death Note </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can edit or preview [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/qvofkauj/)

Comment: yes, this works, thank you!! how do I add that comma after katakana tho??